# Why Spring's ModelAndView object not setting viewname provided?

Tags: spring, jsp, controller

My jsp Page Code:

```
<li><a href="viewAllProducts.htm"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>View All Products</a></li>
```

my Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "viewAllProducts.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET )
public ModelAndView getProductById1(ModelAndView mav,HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
    mav.setViewName("ViewAllProductsPage");
    return mav;
}
```

When this action is called sout is being printed in apache tomcat output window, but page is being set in ModelAndView object..
Can anybody provide a solution?

Browser shows following error :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /AntixxWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/viewAllProducts.jsp

type Status report

message /AntixxWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/viewAllProducts.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
```

Comment: Can you show how you configured your viewResolver in the xml

Comment: How are you trying to access the controller ?

Comment: Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL which you are accessing for your corresponding page.
It seems like you have mis-configured the resources of project in application-context.xml/ -servlet.xml.

You can use below configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As per my knowledge the URL should be like  `http://localhost:8080/project_name/viewAllProducts.htm.`

Answer (score 0):

you returning model view object , replace that with page name that you want
in that page you can get fetch model view object object

Comment: my action name is "viewAllProducts.htm" and page name is "ViewAllProductsPage"